# What does the semicolon in the dictionary definition of a word mean?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, semicolons, dictionaries

Many dictionaries use a semicolon in a meaning for a word. For instance for the word impertinent I have seen:

> "outside the bounds of proper speech or behaviour; impudent; insolent; saucy"

Then there is a synonym explanation of connotations for impertinent, impudent, insolent, and saucy.

My question is: Does the semicolon introduce synonyms always? Does it mean that the word following a semicolon SHARES the meaning of the main entry word you are looking up; that is, the sense preceding the first semicolon in the meaning?

I know that insolent cannot be substituted for impertinent, but maybe impertinent can be substituted for insolent with a loss of connotation.

Just what the heck are these guys who write dictionaries trying to convey with the semicolon in the meaning of a word?

Comment: When you define a word, the definition you read is not really a "sentence" as such so using a period to separate definitions does not make sense. That's why I think the semicolon is preferred in this case. Also when typing the semicolon please introduce one space afterwards. e.g. "behaviour; impudent; insolent; saucy" - the space is important for proper line wrapping behavior when displaying the text

Comment: I'd guess it's a semicolon rather than a comma to emphasise that the synonyms are not necessarily of the close variety.

Comment: A dictionary is not a list of synonyms, it is an explanation of meaning, done by offering similar words and phrases that together produce an approximate sense of the meaning of the word being defined.  Each part of a definition is not something that can be used as an exact substitute in the manner of a *bureau de change* that says 1 dollar = 2 francs or 20 pesos.

Answer (score 6):

What follows the semicolon should not be considered as a separate definition, but either a clarification, or just a slightly different connotation of what is before the semicolon. If it were an entirely different definition, it would be listed under a separate number.

Comment: If it were an entirely different definition, one starts to think that homographs rather than polysemes may be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Because they're not using complete sentences, they need separators between the thoughts (part of a definition). Since it's possible that a single part of the definition for a word requires the use of a comma, a semicolon is used as a separator to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read too much into such things. The choice of the semicolon is somewhat arbitrary; the dictionary editors could have chosen to use a period (full stop), slash, or indeed a bulleted list, were it not for space considerations.

While it's true as Nicole says that each component of the definition might contain commas, necessitating a different separator for the listing (a "[super-comma](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon)" of sorts), I think the larger purpose is clarity. The definition is offering different and equal ways of expressing this sense of the word, that is

> - outside the bounds of proper speech or behaviour
> - impudent
> - insolent
> - saucy

In this specific case, the importance of the semicolon separation may not be obvious, but take for example this definition of *[romantic](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=romantic)* from AHD:

> 2b. Not based on fact; idealized or fictitious

This could be written as

> 2b. Not based on fact, idealized or fictitious

but that could be misinterpreted initially by the reader in various ways:

> 2b. Not based on fact, whether that fact is idealized or fictitious
>   2b. Not based on fact, not idealized, or not fictitious
>   2b. Not based on fact, not based on the idealized, or not based on the fictitious

The semicolon makes clear what the components of the definition actually are.

> 2b.
>
> - Not based on fact
> - Idealized or fictitious

Answer (score 1):

Incomprehensible use of semicolons in dictionaries leads to a lot of confusion.

There is no explanation in English grammar regarding the use of commas and semicolons in dictionary entries.

This is in the field of knowledge of lexicography, which is a branch of linguistics that deals with the creation of dictionaries.

There is very little information on lexicography on the Internet and it is difficult to find a specialist in lexicography to ask him this question.

One way out is to look in the dictionary preface or dictionary conventions. But this only works for paper dictionaries. Online dictionaries usually do not contain any description of how to use them.

Does anyone have the paper version of the Oxford Dictionary of English or another similar paper dictionary? Could you look up what the semicolon means in the preface or the conventions of your dictionary and write here what you can find?

The online Oxford Dictionary of English uses commas and semicolons in its definitions, and it is not clear why it uses commas in some cases and semicolons in others.

For example:
Regular – 4. Used, done, or happening on a habitual basis; usual.
Also – In addition; too.
Good – 2.2 Healthy, strong, or well.
bad – 2.2 Unfavourable; adverse.

The same situation is in the explanatory dictionaries of the Russian language. Semicolons are used in a similar way. This suggests that there is some kind of lexicographic rule that dictionary compilers follow.

In the preface of one well-known paper Russian dictionary, it is said that after a semicolon goes shades of meaning. However, nowhere there is a definition of a shade of meaning.

I suppose that а shade of meaning is a meaning that is slightly different, but not so different that it is necessary to put it into a separate definition under a different number.

Another large Russian academic paper dictionary in the preface says synonyms follow the semicolon. A number of paper dictionaries say nothing at all about this, although semicolons are heavily used in their dictionary entries. Moreover, there are dictionaries where synonyms go separately and, at the same time, there are also words in their dictionary entries separated by semicolons.

This all is very confusing.

The problem comes when we want to precisely determine the meaning of a word.
If synonyms go after a semicolon, then we can not consider them as a part of a definition and ignore them. If after a semicolon there is a shade of meaning, then for complete understanding, we still need to take into account what comes after a semicolon.

From my observations of English and Russian dictionaries, I came to the following conclusion:

The main definition goes up to the semicolon. The semicolon is usually followed by something like synonyms. But they are not entirely synonymous. These words show in what other senses people use and understand a word to be defined. That is, they are like synonyms in one direction.

Let's look at the example from the Online Oxford Dictionary of English:

Regular
4. Used, done, or happening on a habitual basis; usual

The main definition is: "Used, done, or happening on a habitual basis".  In addition, people can use this word, understanding it as "usual". However, it is the synonym in one direction. It does not work in the opposite direction.
"Usual" is not always "regular". So it is not a complete synonym and we cannot use "usual"  interchangeably with "regular".

Comment: A major problem is that most definitions use synonymy, and the regions of overlap of the meanings of synonyms are highly individualistic and hard to expound concisely.  When A is defined using B; C, there will be a Venn diagram of interchangeable possibilities, and one probably has to include situations where A is neither B nor C but somewhere in between. This is a subset of 'neither B nor C'. // This is ignoring the fact that my B is not your B (nor my B from 25 years ago); 'all words are infinitely polysemous'.

Comment: In "Used, done, or happening on a habitual basis; usual", "Used, done, or happening on a habitual basis" is one definition, "usual" is another definition. Commas in the first one indicate "used on a habitual basis" OR "done on a habitual basis" OR "happening on a habitual basis": these are all very similar, so are connected with commas and "or". Then "usual" is presented as slightly further apart using a semicolon, as is commonly done when both semicolons and commas are used in lists.

Answer (score 0):

Summarising every comment here, view semicolons as super-commas where everything in the list has to apply.

For example, this definition of note from OED

> a. trans. To take notice of; to consider or study carefully; to pay attention to; to mark.

is to be interpreted as, to take notice of, to consider or study carefully, to pay attention to, and to mark.

In cases where the statement following the semicolon provides clarification, my rule still applies since both must be applicable as they are just reworded.